# Trouble with PyMongo with conditional update inside of find_and_modify() call

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to do a conditional update to a nested value.  basically one variable in a nested array of 2 variables per array item has a boolean component I want to update based on the string value of the other variable.

I also want to do all of that based on a targeted find query.  I came up with this below, but it doesn't work.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ssl

from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient("somehost", ssl=True, ssl_cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE, replicaSet='rs0')
db = client.maestro
mycollection = db.users
print 'connected, now performing update'
mycollection.find_and_modify(query={'emailAddress':'somedude@someplace.wat'}, update={ "nested.name" : "issomename" }, { "$set": {'nested.$*.value': True}}, upsert=True, full_response=True)
```

This code results in:

```
SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg
```

This makes me think that the find_and_modify() method can't handle the conditional update bit.

Is there some way to achieve this, or have I gone down a wrong path?  What would you all suggest as a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ssl

from pymongo import MongoClient


client = MongoClient("somehost.wat", ssl=True, ssl_cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE, replicaSet='rs0')
db = client.dbname
mycollection = db.docs
user_email = 'user@somehost.wat'
mycollection.update({ "emailAddress": user_email,"nestedvalue": { "$elemMatch" : {"name": "somename"} } }, { "$set": {"nestedvalue.$.value": True}})
```

This did the trick.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of find_any_modify, use update_one if you want to update just one record or update_many in case of many.

The usage is like this:

mycollection.upadte_one({'emailAddress':'somedude@someplace.wat'},{"$set": {'nested.$*.value': True}})

for further detail please go through this link:
https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/python/update/